# Xcode 5.1 NSInteger to int, loss of precision

Tags: objective-c, xcode, int, nsinteger

This might be a mundane question, but I would like to know the best practice. 
Since upgrading to Xcode 5.1, I got a ton of warnings about loss integer precision from NSInteger (aka 'long') to 'int' assuming because of the arm64 switch.

I have been type casting so far to get rid of the warning for example:

```
int number = (int)[self.arrayOfUsers count];
```

or should I just use

```
long number = (int)[self.arrayOfUsers count];
```

Which is "better"? Should I be mostly using longs now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should be doing is using the correct data type:

```
NSUInteger number = [self.arrayOfUsers count];
```

Don't needlessly cast to something like `int`. Use the proper type.

Comment: ahh... I guess I should just not use `int` at all it seems

Comment: It's always best to use the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the same type if you can:

```
NSUInteger number = [self.arrayOfUsers count];
```

Your first suggestion:

```
int number = (int)[self.arrayOfUsers count];
```

would also work fine as long as you're sure, that the array's count will never go over the integer limit (2^31-1).

Comment: Except the `count` method returns an `NSUInteger`, not an `NSInteger`.